# Mysql Workbench Sidebar Missing Completely

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-workbench, linux-mint

My mysql workbench sidebar is not showing up
My machine is currently running **Linux Mint 20.3** and Mysql Workbench Version is **MySQL Workbench CE (GPL) 8.0.29 CE build 1751076**.
[screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBCQ6.png)

Answer (score 1):

On the mac had this problem with 8.0.36.  Downgraded to 8.0.34 and the toolbar re-appeared.  I don't know if this is strictly related to the version, or had something to do with uninstalling and re-installing.  I deleted the previous application before installing the new one even though that shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is a verified bug. See the bug report here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=113653

This is what the sidebar/toolbar *should* look like: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-vertical-toolbar.html

One workaround is to revert to v8.0.34, but that version crashes for me.

Another workaround is to use the keyboard shortcuts for the buttons (see the bug ticket for more info)

Aside: the toolbar is visible, and I can even click buttons and see tooltips, however I just can't see them haha! It happens in either dark or light mode.

Answer (score -1):

Try View->Panels->Show Sidebar.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-navigator.html

Comment: Did that already but still same

Answer (score -1):

It's sounds silly but hope it might help.
I just hovered mouse to the left and dragged it to the right.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP1vz.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was the case for me, it was actually there already but was hidden, I just hovered the mouse and brought it back to life. Was stuck on this for months.
Also View -> Panels -> Show sidebar was not working since the panel was already there but hidden

Answer (score -1):

I registered to post this. I am currently learning basics of SQL and i use VS Code, sqlite and SQL Notebook. I lost connections in sql notebook and couldnt figure it out, but then!

Right click on left side, where Explorer is in VS Code,  that opens menu with active and visible left sidebar menu buttons. one of them was Connections, to activate connection. maybe you hid it, by accident, same as me.